# Iterate over numpy matrix blocks at a time

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix with shape (10980, 10980, 10), and need to iterate it in blocks of (120, 120, 10) at a time.

Comment: `np.reshape` and `np.transform`.

Comment: sory but I cant find np.transform

Comment: my bad, it's [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

Comment: You can slice the array, e.g. `arr[i:i+120, j:j+120, :]`.  But be careful, 10980 is not a multiple of 120, so you'll have problems at the edges.  The `reshape` suggestion only works for evenly divisible blocks, e.g. `arr.reshape((549,20,549,20,10))`.